# Python calling new class object over variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So this is the initialisation of my class:

```
def __init__(self, x, y, item):
        self.itemHolding = item #Holding = Blueprint to place
        print(str(self.itemHolding))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.list = []
```

The string is just for debugging (it prints in example: )

Now I called

```
def update(self):
    if True:
       self.list.append(self.itemHolding(self.x,self.y))
```

What it should do is spawn an item on the position of itself (like a itemspawner or infinity barrel does in games sometimes).

This don't seems to work. Then how do I use the itemHolding variable to make an new instance of that class-object?

Complete code: https://github.com/ddragon15/Overlooked-OvercookedFangame-WIP- its in tiles.py at line 109

edit: What I try to do is adding a new instance (in this case a Onion (in the example a book but that doesn't matter) of this class into existens (which means its addeted to the game and into an list-array which holds it if needet)

I fixed some issues with an if statement in another function and now if I call it it says "TypeError: 'Onlion' object is not callable" which leads me to believe that it tries to access the right class, but doesn't make it into a new instance/object/iDunnoHowItsCalledInPhytonSry.

So here the runthrough from what I understand:
I make a storage (calling the init) in another file
this storage spawns (creates) a new Onion into my world if there is none in this position - so think of it like a gumball-mashine.
If the check for the instance is correct (which should work now) - this is the if true part, it should creat the new Onion and packs it into the same x and y coordinate as the storage is located at.

Comment: `list.append` → `self.list.append`

Comment: Don't shadow builtin names like `list`.

Comment: what is "item", what is "spawn an item on the position of itself" supposed to mean, and what do you mean by "don't seem to work" ?

Comment: list was an example for simplicity.

"item" item is an object passed in from the main.py file. There it is called via: MTiles.append(tiles.Storage(128,189,items.Book))


"spawn an item on the position of itself" means creating a class (in this case book) on the position (x and y) where Storage is created bevore.

Comment: Show us the real code then. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: to self.list.append - yes, but for simplicity say its more like 'otherFile.list.append'

Comment: git to real code addet.

Comment: @ddragon15 I'm afraid your answer to my question is just as unclear as your post. If someone can make sense of it and understand what you're trying to do then you might be lucky, else you will have to try a bit harder... Oh and FWIW, the fact that "item is and object" was already quite clear - in Python everything is an object you know ? - so don't state the obvious...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers
i actually didn't know. Im fairly new in python and just worked a year with C# bevore (since i learned the first programming 2 years ago). So thanks for letting me know in such a nice and modest way. Also im from germany so english is not my nativ language, sorry if my phrasing is confusing im still try to improve on that.

Comment: @ddragon15 I'm not a native English speaker either, nor are most people here.  Which is why it's even more important to try to be as clear as possible if one expects to get any meaningful answer...

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers As you can see i tried to improve on that. Think of it like code - this being my first question here - does your code run everytime you try it at the first time? From what i got out of your message (this is just how it loked to me) you just rented over the lag of explanation but didn't gave me something substential to improve it on. I don't think you wanted to be unconstructive, but you also failed in explaining yourself what is missing for you to understand my question. <- does that make any sense to you?

Comment: I ran through the game and the only typo I found was `"resources/images/cuttingBoard.jpg"` → `"resources/images/cuttingboard.jpg"`.

Comment: @pacholik I make a new commit (did some cleaning in the last hour or so) so you are uptodate.
try to walk(wasd) against the container (the box with the dark gradient) and press space. It should give an error about the line 108 saying: `Onion object is not callable`

Comment: No error. Got an onion…

Comment: @pacholik http://imgur.com/a/TmiKq heres a give of my console when the problem happens

Comment: No errors here.

Comment: that bit is for spawning a new onion if there is none over the black void of the storage box, so you can make onions like here in an earlier build: http://i.imgur.com/MPMJ4PE.gif this worked, but had some really bad practise to do so. It seems to me as the efficient way to set the item the storage should spawn at the instantiation of the crate itself (see game.py line 85) then use that variable to spawn that onion.

Comment: @pacholik OH im sorry. I just saw i didn't push the changes and cleanups (-.-) so that part was simply my absolute and perfekt stupidety. Now it should show you the latest build. Commit d992e52 should be the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `itemHolding` member is supposed to be a *type* for whole runtime.

It turns out you're substituting it for an *instance*. It is happening in the parent class.

```
class All():
    ...
    def itemCheck(self):
        ...
            self.itemHolding = i
```

In this case, *i* is an *instance* of *Onion*.

Though I'm not completely sure what are you doing there, I thing you want to replace it with

```
self.itemHolding = type(i)
```

Comment: Your right... didn't saw that. I check that right away. Probably thats the whole problem.

Comment: So and there comes the whole avalanche... which is a good thing in solving my problem. spaceChecker and itemCheck are basicly the same function ontop of eachother... did a number on that. anyways i try to get it run by taking `self.itemHolding=i` out for now

Comment: and it works. The if statement for spawning is kinda reversed but when it comes to what i wanted to accomplish you solved it - big thx :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use self.list instead of list for the second block so it should be

```
def update(self):
    if True:
        self.list.append(self.itemHolding(self.x,self.y))
```

This is so it can use the list variable in self

Comment: that is right, i fixed it in the question.
Thats just a typo i made in giving the example code. The list works in the original (see git) but it is located in another file.